# reading header lines generated value error

Tags: python, numpy

here is my binary file:
ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/3B42RT/3B42RT.2014010318.7.bin.gz

I tried to read the header lines as follows:

```
fname = '3B42RT.2014010318.7.bin'

with open(fname, 'rb') as fi:

    header = np.fromfile(fi,dtype='S',count=2880)
    print header
```

I got ValueError: The elements are 0-sized.
The IDL file says the number of header lines are 2880, so I put count as 2880.

ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/software/read_rt_file.pro

Any ideas please.

Comment: You need to unzip it first.

Comment: i did unzip, ofcourse

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: the filename in the code suggests they did that already.

Comment: There are specs here: ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/V7Documents/3B4XRT_README.pdf and in the sibling files.  There's even C and Fortran code if you look in that directory!

Comment: @John Zwinck I want to use only Python

Comment: @JohnZwinck So i am trying to read the data (precipitation) inside the file using Pyhton. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, I could write the code for you, but I'd usually expect payment for that.  Failing that, my advice is read through as much of those specs as you can stand, find the smallest file you can, and work through it methodically.  I didn't suggest the C and Fortran code for you to use it directly, more like a guide you could work from.  Be sure to see the "struct" package in Python, which lets you read packed binary data--you may need finer control that what NumPy gives you (I'm not sure yet).

Comment: @JohnZwinck no job, no money sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From closer inspection:

```
00000040  31 34 30 31 30 33 31 38  2e 37 2e 62 69 6e 20 68  |14010318.7.bin h|
00000050  65 61 64 65 72 5f 62 79  74 65 5f 6c 65 6e 67 74  |eader_byte_lengt|
00000060  68 3d 32 38 38 30 20 66  69 6c 65 5f 62 79 74 65  |h=2880 file_byte|
00000070  5f 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3d  28 63 68 61 72 32 38 38  |_length=(char288|
00000080  30 29 5f 68 65 61 64 65  72 2b 28 69 6e 74 32 29  |0)_header+(int2)|
00000090  78 31 34 34 30 78 34 38  30 78 32 5f 64 61 74 61  |x1440x480x2_data|
000000a0  2b 28 69 6e 74 31 29 78  31 34 34 30 78 34 38 30  |+(int1)x1440x480|
000000b0  5f 64 61 74 61 2b 28 69  6e 74 32 29 78 31 34 34  |_data+(int2)x144|
000000c0  30 78 34 38 30 5f 64 61  74 61 20 6e 6f 6d 69 6e  |0x480_data nomin|
```

If appears that the header length is stored in the `header_byte_length` header field. That leads to that little parser (I let error handling and "beautification" up to you).

```
fname = '3B42RT.2014010318.7.bin'

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    headers = { 'header_byte_length': "999999" } 
    pos = 0

    acc = ""
    while pos < int(headers['header_byte_length']):
        c = fi.read(1)
        pos += 1
        if c == ' ':
            try:
                k,v = acc.split('=')
                headers[k] = v
            except ValueError:
                pass
            acc = ''
        else:
            acc += c

    print headers
    print "Data starts a offset ",headers['header_byte_length']

    fi.seek(int(headers['header_byte_length']))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got ValueError: The elements are 0-sized.

As far as I can tell, the `S` specifier is to read fixed length string. You *have* to provide a length specifier:

```
header = np.fromfile(fi,dtype='S50',count=2880)
```

---

That being said, from a dump of your file:

```
00000000  61 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68  6d 5f 49 44 3d 33 42 34  |algorithm_ID=3B4|
00000010  32 52 54 20 61 6c 67 6f  72 69 74 68 6d 5f 76 65  |2RT algorithm_ve|
00000020  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 30 37  2e 30 30 20 67 72 61 6e  |rsion=07.00 gran|
[...]
00000480  2e 67 6f 76 20 72 75 6e  5f 6c 61 74 65 6e 63 79  |.gov run_latency|
00000490  3d 4c 41 53 54 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |=LAST           |
000004a0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
*
00000b40  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00000db0  ff ff 83 01 83 01 83 01  83 01 83 01 83 01 83 01  |................|
```

The various headers are variable length and delimited by spaces (`'\x20'`). You probably have to find an other way to parse those data.